# Angular material vertically center button next to matInput

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, material-ui, angular-material

How do I in Angular material vertically center button next to matInput? As you can see on the picture below, the submit button is too low to be aligned with the "First Name" input field.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can answer by forking my stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-q8jcfe?file=app/my-form/my-form.component.css

This mat-form-field-wrapper padding-bottom is a pain in the ass. I know what it's for, but still.

I am not allowed to use magic numbers to align this button.

This should be a pretty common task, I am wondering why material doesn't provide a simply way for the button to always be aligned to the right, or why noone has asked this before on stackoverflow.

I want it to look nice always (e.g. when input changes height or button changes height), I don't have any concrete design-idea but how it below is obviously looks off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and set parent `div` element for button that contains same css as the padding `div`element that is sibling to `ìnput`element. So my solution in this case would be something like:

```
<div class="mat-form-field-wrapper">
 <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

I've forked you repo and provided solution.

[image]

Comment: "I've forked you repo and provided solution." where can I see your forked repo of mine? Could you provide a link in your answer?

Comment: I have actually tried something similar to your solution but it used magic numbers (which is bad, espeically "padding-bottom: **1.34375em**;") and even then it still didn't look centered. Maybe you could provide a link with the solution to your fork of my stackblitz?

Comment: Oh my apologies: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-cdfwmh?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: You need to append same classes. If you someday want to overwrite material classes (in this case ```mat-form-field-wrapper```) button will be aligned automatically.

Comment: Wow ok this actually works with no magic numbers, just by adding a "mat-form-field-wrapper". I considered this but thought this would be ViewEncapsulated material-styles, nevermind I guess. You really merit your stackblitz username

Comment: Actually this solution does not 100% fulfill my question, see:

"I want it to look nice always (e.g. when input changes height or button changes height)"

. add a class with "display: flex; align-items: center" to the same div that has "mat-form-field-wrapper" for the button to be centered, even when the input-height changes. This was the case in my application.

Comment: Only worked because by coincidence in your stackblitz the button and the input have roughly the same height

Comment: In other words I was missing ```align-items``` in the provided solution or I understood latest comments wrong mate?

Comment: Understood comments wrong. Outer container around [input,button-div] should be `display: flex;`
Inner container button-div should be `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: It only worked in your stackblitz because by coincidence in your stackblitz the button and the input have roughly the same height